# What is the regular expression that generates the language where every odd position in the string is an a?

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression that generates the language where every odd position in the string is an a? (Please answer with the shortest possible regex: minimal parentheses, no spaces and any piped strings in alphabetical order!)

I assume I'm working with only a's and b's.

(a(a|b))+ would only cover even strings: a(a|b), a(a|b)a(a|b), etc.

How do I also cover the case that the string is odd? ex: a(a|b)a

**Note: not using programming syntax**

Edit: some valid strings would be: a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa, ab, aba, abab, ababa, etc.

**EDIT: Solution**

My instructor gave the answer (aa|ab)*. This is incorrect because it misses case(s), for example "a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this suits your requirement:

```
^a(.a)*.?$
```

- Position 1 must be "a": ^a
- Repetitions of any character + a, making a sequence where odds are "a"'s: (.a)*
- Allowing for a termination not ending in "a", ex abab: .?$

You can check it here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tmIvHU/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(a.)*a?$
```

- Allows empty values ("")
- From start to end of line (`^...$`)
- Every odd place (1,3,5,...) is an a followed by any letter/number
- There may or may not be an a in the end
- One sign shorter thay Jorge's answer, but allows empty values

See regex101 example [here](https://regex101.com/r/jw0PzO/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

- Case 1: even length strings `(1(0+1))*`
- Case 2: odd length strings `1((0+1)1)*`

Finally the answer is `Case 1 + Case 2`